# C get a signal to send a value

Tags: c, signals

Is it possible using signals in C to have a parent and child process running, and when randomly control C (SIGINT) is pressed, a integer is given to the parent to pass to the child via a pipe.

pseudo code:

```
main:
-call firstfunction

handler:
-handler for SIGINT
-call second function if SIGINT is live

firstfunction:
-create pipe, fork for child
-let OS know to handle SIGINT

secondfunction:
-handler for control C signal
-return a INT value to firstfunction parent process
```

I'm struggling trying to see how would I go about the secondfunction actual code.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing. On line#1

Comment: Sorry? Its pseduco code.

Comment: "randomly" is very different than "asynchronous".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Standard C all you are allowed to do is to set an atomic flag in the signal handler, via a global variable of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`.

So your signal handler sets the flag and returns; and your main loop will poll this flag to see if any signals have been received. Your main loop then sends the message to child when it detects the flag.

Specific operating systems may or may not permit you to do more in the signal handler (e.g. open the pipe and send something).